# mysqldump script fails on update from mysql 5.5 to 5.7

Tags: mysql

I have updated our database from mySQL 5.5 to 5.7.The overnight cron database backup now fails. The script hasn't changed because the database login details are in a separate config script. If I set the login details back to the old database it works as before.

This is the key line of the PHP script:

```
$command = 'mysqldump --opt -h ' . DB_HOST . ' -u' . DB_USERNAME .' -p' . DB_PASSWORD . ' ' . DB_NAME . ' > ' . $db['Export'];
```

And this is the error message cron emailed:

```
sh: 1: Gp+cYE2!6z: not found
```

Can anyone suggest what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a mistake in `$command`.

Is `Gp+cYE2!6z:` a part of your password? Is it a full pass? Does it have spaces?

Try: `printf($command)` to see the final text of the comand and try to execute it in terminal.

You can also try to quote password as done followingly:

```
mysqldump -u root -p'PASSWORD'
```

Comment: You're quite correct. I hadn't associated the error string with the automatically-generated password. The problem was the password had a & character in it. Many thanks!